# .offset().topについて

Tags: javascript, jquery

・jQueryの.offset().topは、ドキュメントの左上からのy軸方向の距離とかいてあったのですが、JavaScriptの.offsetTopプロパティのオフセットと意味は異なるのですか？
・offsetParent ノードかどうかは関係ない？？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSSOM View の offsetTop](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop) は `offsetParent` 左上からの相対座標なので、`offsetParent` が <body> ではない場合は jQuery の `.offset().top` とは異なります。下は、同じ要素で`offsetTop` と `.offset().top` が異なる例です。

```js
function log(mes) {
  $('pre')[0].textContent += mes + '\n';
}

var target = $('.target');
log('offsetTop: ' + target[0].offsetTop);
log('offset().top: ' + target.offset().top);
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.target {
  height: 20px;
  background: lime;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="target"></div>
</div>
<pre>
</pre>
```